# Azure Functions: How do you use a POCO in a binding expression with Azure Storage Queue?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues, azure-function-app

I've got an Azure Function defined that uses an Azure Storage Queue Trigger and Blob input bindings.  I've got a POCO for the queue trigger but how can I use that POCO with a binding expression in the blob input binding?

**Architecuture:**

1. Azure Functions 2.x
2. Precompiled C# library (.NET Core 2.1)

**POCO:**

```
public class ImageToProcess
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string FullImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

**Azure Function:**

```
public static void Run(
    [QueueTrigger("profile-image-queue", Connection = "ProfileImageQueue")]ImageToProcess myQueueItem,
    [Blob("profileimages/{queueTrigger.FullImagePath}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "ProfileImageBlobConnectionString")] Stream originalImage,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"Started Processing profile image: myQueueItem");
}
```

**Queue Message:**

```
{ 
    "CompanyId": 123,
    "FullImagePath": "CompanyA/profileImage-original.png" 
}
```

**Error Message:**

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: ProfileImageUploaded. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Exception binding parameter 'originalImage'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while accessing 'FullImagePath': property doesn't exist.

**Resources Used to Create this Solution**

1. http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Improving-Azure-Functions-Blob-Trigger-Performance-and-Reliability-Part-2-Processing-Delays-and-Missed-Blobs
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger
3. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/functions-recipes/queue-storage#azure-storage-queue-trigger-using-a-poco

**Other Potential Solution:**
The only other option I see is to use imperative bindings but I'm pretty sure I can use declarative.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#binding-at-runtime

Comment: use the following:  *"profileimages/{FullImagePath}"* or *"{FullImagePath}"* in the case of the url address

Comment: @RomanKiss - That fixed it but how does the function know that the property is from the "QueueTrigger" meta data and not some other meta data property? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue#trigger---message-metadata

Comment: @RomanKiss - After thinking about it I guess the compiler assumes you are trying to reference a property on the queueTrigger meta data because the other meta data properties you must reference by name?  Either way, if you add your answer to my post I'll accept it.

Comment: have a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns, also it is based on the trigger metadata, e.g. the HttpTrigger will concern a query string, headers. etc., so then *{query.myid}, {headers.myid}*, etc.

Comment: @RomanKiss - Yep, this statement under the "JSON payloads" confirms your answer "Notice that the Blob input binding gets the blob name by referring directly to the BlobName property ("path": "strings/{BlobName}")"  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the following in the Blob binding:

```
"profileimages/{FullImagePath}"
```

Note, if the *FullImagePath* represents a url address, than:

```
"{FullImagePath}"
```

Comment: Here is the documentation for this: [JSON Payloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#json-payloads)

Comment: Without any changes to my application this approach is now suddenly failing.